# Validation Formulas not working on a specific site

Tags: list, column, validation

I have troubles using validation formulas on *one specific* site. Within a large sharepoint I was working on one site and had no problems using validation formulas.

Now I now want to implement these validations on a different site, but keep getting an error every time I want to use even the simplest validation formula. The message says:

> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

As I copied and pasted correct formulas, I suspect the latter is true. Is there a way to disable/enable Column Validations on one site?

Comment: Are you using different regional settings on the sites?

Comment: Indeed, I have. It's working on German, but not working on English (United States). I just changed English to German and now formulas are working?! How is this causing problems? I am not using localized functions.. Huh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common reason (when there is no error in the formula) is that sites with different regional settings uses different characters as a delimiter.

For European countries, commas works (,) work while English uses semicolon (;).

So try to change all the semicolons (,) to commas (;) for it to work in your English page and vice versa. Use find and replace in any text editor for your validations and it should work.

If you wanna take a deep dive into the subject, check out this Wikipedia article.

[Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Comment: Uh, I feel so stupid. That explains it. I am writing my formulas within Excel and Excel's language is set to English. That's why I was not thinking about that problem. The separators are not affected by the language and have to be changed manually. Thanks for your quick help! :)

Comment: Don't, this gets me every time. :)